# Client-side роутинг. Алгоритм. Без хэша(#) в адресной строке

Tags: javascript, маршрутизация, html5-history-api

Собственно, ситуация следующая: Есть замечательное HTML5 History API, с его помощью получается организовать удобную навигацию, скажем в каком-нибудь Single Page Application.

Вот [пример](http://html5demos.com/history). Все замечательно, при работе имеем красивые URL а-ля:

- http://html5demos.com/history/first
- http://html5demos.com/history/second

и так далее.

**Проблема**
Если же я хочу с кем-то поделиться ссылкой именно вида: http://html5demos.com/history/first, то просто вбив такой URL в адресную строку сервер вежливо сообщит, что запрос некорректен.

**Вопрос**
Решается ли как-то вышеописанная проблема на клиентской стороне, не прибегая к использованию хэшей в ссылках?

P.S. Я не настолько ниндзя JS, чтобы получалось построчно разбирать какие-нибудь тяжеловесные фреймворки(возможно, которые могут похвастаться фичей, которая устраняет проблему).
P.S.S. Буду признателен за любые ответы, комментарии, подсказки.

Comment: это должно решаться сервером, т.е. должен поддерживаться роутинг на сервере

Comment: Иными словами, вопрос мой абсурден, т.к. до того, пока классический сервер, что отдает статику не обработает неправильный(в контексте файловой структуры документов) запрос, собственно никакого клиентского JS писать не приходится? То есть, без сервера, это будет только решение с хэшем и ссылками вида: http://html5demos.com/#/history/first, правильно?

Comment: Сервер, как минимум, должен все запросы перенаправлять на одну конкретную страницу, можно и без роутинга (например, внутренний редирект). Но на клиенте тогда нужно средствами JS парсить урл и вычленять из него нужные элементы руками. Пример здесь: https://habrahabr.ru/post/252533/

Comment: Спасибо. Вопросов больше не имею.